# Property null when receiving on web api

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have the following method in my web api

```
public class AccessPanelController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage PostGrantAccess([FromUri]GrantAccessRequest grantAccessRequest)
        {
            var deviceId = grantAccessRequest.DeviceId;

            var grantAccessResponse = new GrantAccessResponse()
                {
                    Status = "OK"
                };
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<GrantAccessResponse>(HttpStatusCode.OK, grantAccessResponse);
            return response;
        }

    }
```

GrantAccessRequest class:

```
public class GrantAccessRequest
{
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
}
```

Client:

```
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55208/");

            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            Uri uri = null;

            var request = new GrantAccessRequest { DeviceId = "bla" };
            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/accesspanel", uri).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                uri = response.Headers.Location;
            }
```

In my `PostGrantAccess` method, `grantAccessRequest` is constructed, but `DeviceId` is null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the `[FromUri]` attribute on your controller action. Also on the client you don't seem to be doing anything with the `request` variable which is containing the payload:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostGrantAccess(GrantAccessRequest grantAccessRequest)
```

To better understand how model binding works in the Web API I recommend you reading the [`following article`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx).

So:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55208/");

    var request = new GrantAccessRequest { DeviceId = "bla" };
    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/accesspanel", request).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var uri = response.Headers.Location;
    }
}
```

Notice that you don't need to set the `Accept` request header in this case because you are using the `PostAsJsonAsync` method.

Also I don't know if this is a typo in your question but you seem to have specified `api/accesspanel` as url whereas your controller action is called `GrantAccessRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

Well this looks problematic to start with:

```
Uri uri = null;
var request = new GrantAccessRequest { DeviceId = "bla" };
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/accesspanel", uri).Result;
```

You're never doing anything with `request`, and `uri` will always be null. How are you expecting the device ID to make it through to the server?

(I confess I don't know enough about WebAPI to know exactly how you're expected to fix this, but presumably you want to use `request` *somewhere* in the `PostAsJsonAsync` call... Given the `[FromUri]` attribute, I'd expect something to convert that data to part of the URI to use.)